# rails with carrierwave migration error: undefined method `attachment'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave, rails-migrations

I'm using carrierwave gem ( ver. 0.8.0 ). When I make 'rake db:migrate', I see strange error:

```
    ==  AddAttachmentLogoToMerchants: migrating ===================================
    -- change_table(:merchants)
    rake aborted!
    An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

    undefined method `attachment' for     ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter::Table:0x007f900e6bde88
```

My migration:

```
      def self.up
        change_table :merchants  do |t|
          t.attachment :logo
        end
        remove_column :merchants, :logo_filename
      end

      def self.down
        add_column :merchants, :logo_filename, :string
        drop_attached_file :merchants, :logo
      end
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: it not help me, still have 'undefined method `attachment''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK in `t.attachment` `attachment` should be a datatype

```
change_table :merchants  do |t|
  t.attachment :logo
end
```

Please [click here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype.html) to find datatype list for postgresql
If you want string following should work

```
change_table :merchants  do |t|
  t.string :logo
end
```